# WPF Sliding Window

Tags: c#, wpf, window, sliding

Does anyone know the correct definition for a "sliding window" in WPF? What I have in mind is like the "Pending Changes" or "Call Stack" window in Visual Studio - where you click it and it slides up, and then you move your mouse away and it slides down again.

I am happy to spend some time researching how to do this, I just don't know where to start because I'm not sure what exactly this feature is called.

Any comments appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is mostly called 'Auto Hide' feature for the window.

There is a very good example on CodeProject: [WPF Docking Library](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18812/WPF-Docking-Library)
Also have a look on [AvalonDock](http://avalondock.codeplex.com/).

Comment: use avalon docking lib; seems like the best one out there so far. I have also used Telerik docking, it's getting better, but you gotta pay $$$ for telerik

Answer (score 1):

Is this Avalon Dock you are talking about?

If it is look at the circled area in image and this link will help you
http://avalondock.codeplex.com

[image: Look at the circled area]